# How can i refresh a Razor page from a static void method in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-5, razor-pages

I have a Razor page(View of `PayProduct()`) that displayed some sessions value. This sessions values have be changed in `Void Main()` methods.So how can i display this new sessions value in Razor Page.

```
public static class pay
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
          //Changed the sessions values 
          HttpContext.Current.Session["TrackingCode"]="123ab456"
          //return or refresh razor page of  PayProduct()  or...?.
        }
    }

 public class ExamplesController : Controller
    {
     public ActionResult PayProduct()
        {
          //somethings
         return View()// display the sessions value
        }
    }
```

The PayProduct() razor page

```
if(HttpContext.Current.Session["TrackingCode"] != null)
            {
                <div class="alert alert-info">
                    @HttpContext.Current.Session["TrackingCode"].ToString()
                </div>
            }
```

What is your solution for this problem. Thanks

Comment: What is it you are trying to do (do not describe how you are trying to do it which you already did)? What is the purpose of the code you are writing.

Comment: The question is unclear. Redirection is something the *browser* does, in response to a 302 response. The question's code doesn't even call a web site though, it calls a controller's method directly. What are you really trying to do? Write a unit test for a controller perhaps?

Comment: look, I have a View that displayed some session. This sessions value has been changed in ```void Main()``` method.So how can i display this new values?

Comment: @Aram What do you mean by "sessions values"? Are you using `Session` in you code? If so, why you're not showing us the code instead of this bunch of commented lines up there?

Comment: @Aram Who's the caller of the `Main` method? if its not an action show us where its called.

Comment: @Aram repeating the question won't make it clearer. This is still a console application, still not displaying anything, still calling just a method, not a web site. Asking about displaying a view makes no sense - . What would make sense would be if you had a *web app* and wanted to modify the session data from a method outside the controller that gets called by ... what? What are you trying to do? By design, only code running *inside* a session has access to the session's data. A session isn't a generic cache, there are separate mechanisms for caching and refreshing lookup data

Comment: @Aram when you have a web site serving 100 concurrent users you have 100 active sessions. Outside a controller's action there is no single current session, there are 100 active sessions.

Comment: @Aram If *the real question* how to refresh an order page after payment? Or how to store payment data? For starters, you don't use the session for this, you use the database, so even if the web app crashes the information won't be lost. The *browser* can refresh the payment page periodically to check for completion, or poll an API to do the same. the `Pay` action can redirect to a `processing` page that refreshes itself periodically, redirecting to another page once payment is complete